# Android Login application with mysql

Tags: android, mysql, database, android-activity, authentication

I'm new in Android development so sorry if my questions are really silly.
I'm trying to conform a Login Activity which just check if the user and password are in the data base, is it possible or should I be connected to a Web Service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm new in Android development so sorry if my questions are really
>   silly

I have no problem, but people love to downvotes this kind of question (or even my answer - even if i only try to help).

> should I be connected to a Web Service?

No offense, but judging from your question, you are new in android/programming in general. If you dont want your apps to connect to a server via webservice, you can just use `SQLite` for **local** database.

Be aware that the user's data is local (which is very bad, **only** use this for training), means you and your user cant do anything if something happened to the data so never use it on the real apps. Always use `webservice` if you are building a real apps with real user.

Comment: I just was trying to avoid WebServices because I'm new in programming and I wanted to start with simple applications. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @colibriii Yes, SQLite is a way to go :) Please accept my answer if it help you. Good luck :)